# round up string.Format in c#

Tags: c#, string, rounding

I have the next round up dilemma:

```
hn = 143;
label6.Text = string.Format("{0} mm", hn.ToString("N0"));
```

And a want it to show in the Label Text at the next multiple of 5.
Like:

143 to show 145.

141 to show 145.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you mean the next multiple of 5?

Comment: Alright, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: Couple of adding and multipling but no %. Got to learn more about this operators, just been around c# for 2,3 days. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var val = (hn % 5 == 0)?hn:hn + (5 - hn % 5);
label6.Text = string.Format("{0} mm", val.ToString("N0"));
```

Comment: @Moo-Juice - Though slightly different approaches to the false branch.

Answer (score 3):

Could use Math.Ceiling among other approaches

```
(Math.Ceiling(hn/5.0)) * 5
```

Answer (score 1):

To round up to the next multiple, you could use something like:

```
int test = 143;
int result = (test % 5 == 0) ? test : ((test + 5) / 5) * 5;
```